# Google LineChart: add a graph of the sum of the readings of other graphs

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have data for the graph that contain 4 columns (X axis values with type datetime and 3 Y axis values with type number). And I'm building a chart with 3 lines (nothing unusual):

```
var chartDataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
// get data to chartDataTableRows variable by ajax
chartDataTable.addRows(chartDataTableRows);
var _chartContainer = $('<div id="_chart"</div>').appendTo($('#_tempChart'));
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(_chartContainer[0]);
chart.draw(chartDataTable, defaultChartOptions());
```

Now I need to add to the chart one more line that will display the sum of the indicators of the existing three lines. Are there any such tools in GoogleCharts?

Comment: This will come handy [Google.Visualization.Data.Sum](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference?csw=1#data_aggregation_functions)

Comment: @Pirate X, but i need sum of row values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a `DataView` with a calculated column for the total

1) create a `DataView` over the `DataTable`

```
var chartDataView = new google.visualization.DataView(chartDataTable);
```

2) use the `setColumns` method to provide the columns for the `DataView`
provide the column index for the existing columns,
and a calculated column for the total...

```
chartDataView.setColumns([0, 1, 2, 3, {
  type: 'number',
  label: 'total',
  calc: function (dt, row) {
    var rowTotal = 0;
    for (var col = 1; col < chartDataTable.getNumberOfColumns(); col++) {
      rowTotal += chartDataTable.getValue(row, col);
    }
    return rowTotal;
  }
}]);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var chartDataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  chartDataTable.addColumn('date', 'x');
  chartDataTable.addColumn('number', 'y0');
  chartDataTable.addColumn('number', 'y1');
  chartDataTable.addColumn('number', 'y2');
  chartDataTable.addRows([
    [new Date(2018, 2, 28), 5, 2, 8],
    [new Date(2018, 2, 29), 7, 3, 6],
    [new Date(2018, 2, 30), 3, 0, 9],
    [new Date(2018, 2, 31), 1, 5, 9],
    [new Date(2018, 3, 1), 3, 6, 7],
    [new Date(2018, 3, 2), 4, 7, 8],
    [new Date(2018, 3, 3), 3, 1, 8],
    [new Date(2018, 3, 4), 4, 2, 6],
    [new Date(2018, 3, 5), 2, 3, 5]
  ]);

  var chartDataView = new google.visualization.DataView(chartDataTable);
  chartDataView.setColumns([0, 1, 2, 3, {
    type: 'number',
    label: 'total',
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      var rowTotal = 0;
      for (var col = 1; col < chartDataTable.getNumberOfColumns(); col++) {
        rowTotal += chartDataTable.getValue(row, col);
      }
      return rowTotal;
    }
  }]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(chartDataView);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```